# PHP, class variables and var

Tags: php, class

I was looking up the syntax of `extends` and noticed that a class variable begins with `var`: http://www.php.net//manual/en/keyword.extends.php

I have written some PHP classes before, never used `var`, and it appeared to work just fine (no errors, could use the variable just fine). In addition, not even defining a variable inside the class other than in the constructor such as `$this->foo = "bar"` also seems to work just fine.

To be clear on the differences, here are some brief examples:

```
<?php
    class ExA {
        var $foo;
        function __construct() {
            $this->foo = "bar";
        }
    }

    class ExB {
        $foo;
        function __construct() {
            $this->foo = "bar";
        }
    }

    class ExC {
        function __construct() {
            $this->foo = "bar";
        }
    }
?>
```

What is the purpose of `var`? Is there a problem with the last example or is it different from the other two in any way?

Comment: Class variables in ["modern" PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) are identified with a visibility (`private`, `protected` or `public`), not with `var`, which only exists for backward compatibility. If yu don't define visibility, then all properties will be public

Comment: @MarkBaker, in other words, ignore `var` and use `private`, `protected`, or `public` always?

Comment: That's the official PHP recommendation: Use of `var` was deprecated for a time, but so many developers refused to stop using it that they had to undeprecate it again (one of the issues that holds PHP core development back)

Comment: Also, in my last example, `$this->foo` is `public` even though I did not explicitly say so right?

Comment: Correct `$this->foo` will be public in all your examples; easily testable by trying to access the value from outside the instance: `$inst = new ExC(); echo $inst->foo;`

Comment: Also your second example will throe an error, saying that, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION on line x`. You can't use just `$foo` inside a `class` outside any function/method.